# Does casting a spell on a weapon make it count as magic for bypassing immunities or resistances?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, weapons, immunities

I'm wondering if a weapon ***"wrapped"*** in a spell like Prestidigitation, Minor Illusion, or another like spell would classify as making my weapon a magical weapon for combat in regards to resistance or immunity to non-magical weapons and attacks?

For example: As I enter combat I go to draw my sword from its sheath and let out a battle cry which makes the blade burst into flames making it appear a "Blazing Blade" but in reality is nothing more than a standard weapon encased in magical flames of harmlessness. Would this bypass the magic requirement?

Comment: Possible dupe of: [How do you distinguish between magic effects that bypass immunity and those that don't?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83153/how-do-you-distinguish-between-magic-effects-that-bypass-immunity-and-those-that)

Answer (score 24):

### Only certain spells turn weapons magical.

The spell *Magic Weapon* specifies:

> You touch a nonmagical weapon. Until the spell ends, that weapon becomes a magic weapon with a +1 bonus to Attack rolls and Damage Rolls.

Likewise, the spell *Elemental Weapon* states:

> A nonmagical weapon you touch becomes a magic weapon.

If casting any spell on a weapon makes it a magic weapon, these spells wouldn't have to specify that they turn nonmagical weapons into magic weapons.

For an in-universe explanation, only spells that explicitly add magic to a weapon would affect whether a weapon was magical or not. Since spells like light or minor illusion don't deal damage on their own, and don't fundamentally modify whatever they're cast on, they don't add the magical quality to the weapon. Additionally, polymorphing a weapon only changes its physical form, and doesn't add any magical properties.

### Developer intent supports this.

As Purple Monkey points out, Jeremy Crawford, the lead rules designer for 5e, [confirms this](https://twitter.com/RCPlemons/status/808836086466224128):

> **What just happened?**
> @RCPlemons

> @JeremyECrawford Would casting the light cantrip on a weapon render it a magic weapon in regards to resistance to non magical weapons?

> **Jeremy Crawford**
> @JeremyECrawford

> @RCPlemons No.

Answer (score 15):

This would not bypass resistance or immunity to non-magical weapons.

Jeremy Crawford, the lead rules designer for D&D 5e, has answered pretty much this exact question with [this unofficial ruling:](https://twitter.com/RCPlemons/status/808836086466224128)

> **What just happened?**
> <sup>@RCPlemons</sup>
> @JeremyECrawford Would casting the light cantrip on a weapon render it a magic weapon in regards to resistance to non magical weapons?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford**
> <sup>@JeremyECrawford</sup>
> @RCPlemons No.

Whilst he doesn't go into any detail about explaining *why* this is the case, it's clear the intent is that simply casting a spell on an item doesn't make the item itself magical.

Comment: Then what of Green Flame Blade and Booming Blade? Does the magic from the cantrip make the weapon a magical attack just for the single attack or is it a spell that encases a weapon in a magical aura that first contacts the enemy and then the weapon strikes?