# Does attacking with an improvised weapon using a magic item count as a magical attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attack, improvised-weaponry

Inspired by the recent question: "[Are there mechanics that will make improvised weapon attacks magical for a pure fighter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159907)"

Answers there are basically debating whether improvised attacks with magic items count as magical attacks when perhaps there are options besides improvised attacks with magic items to accomplish that goal.

To hopefully get at something there, I'm asking this separately; I'm wondering whether an improvised attack made using a magic item (like a broom of flying or even throwing a ring of spell storing) actually counts as magical and thus overcomes resistances to non-magical attacks/damage.

Note that the other question asks about *any* way to accomplish having improvised attacks count as magical, and I'm asking whether this specific method works (instead of having it be disagreed upon in answers over there).

Comment: Yeah, it's close. I mean, a punch is not. But a punch with the gauntlets seems like it might be. Either way, these questions seem super similar, but i'm not willing to use a dupe hammer on it and will let others decide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Does a magic item used as an improvised weapon count as a magic weapon?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98832/does-a-magic-item-used-as-an-improvised-weapon-count-as-a-magic-weapon) . That question doesn't have a satisfactory answer either.

Answer (score 1):

To make a "magical attack", you have to meet one of three conditions:

> ... a magical attack is an attack delivered by a spell, **a magic item**, or another magical source

An improvised item is potentially a magic item, but it is not necessarily a magic weapon.  [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/774040344254046208) has stated:

> A magic shield is not a magic weapon, unless its text says otherwise.

That says nothing about being a magic “improvised” weapon or not. It may be the same to him but either way it is unofficial or RAI at best.

The PHB describes an improvised weapon as the following:

> Sometimes characters don’t have their Weapons and have to Attack with **whatever is at hand**. An Improvised Weapon includes **any object** you can wield in one or two hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a wagon wheel, or a dead Goblin.

A set of Sending Stones in the hand would be in line with the Improvised portion of this. Sending Stones being used to hit someone in the head would be the same as regular rocks. Would this make it magical attacks? Yes, based on the description of magical attacks laid out earlier. Sending stones are a magic item and can be improvised.

Note: Sending Stones are being used as an example and there are many other magic items that would apply.