# Do magic items (weapons) all get +1?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, magic, magic-items

In a DND 5E game, my character has the staff of healing. Does this count as a staff/quarter staff for melee purposes? If so, does it get +1 to attack and damage rolls for for being magical?

The spell Magic Weapon reads

> You touch a nonmagical weapon. Until the spell ends, that weapon becomes a magic weapon with a +1 bonus to Attack rolls and Damage Rolls."

This would imply that all weapons that are magical in some way would have a natural +1 to attack and damage rolls (unless stated otherwise or of a higher value)

So does the staff of healing get +1 to attack and damage rolls?

Comment: I believe the question linked directly addresses your question. If that's not the case please edit your question to make the difference clearer and flag it for reopening. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot think of any clearer way to say it.  But from the link there would imply if the items description does not say so, then no.  do you agree?

Comment: Yes--some weapons (staves, particularly), are magic weapons (mostly important for purposes of bypassing resistance/immunity) but have no pluses to hit or damage rolls. I'm second-guessing the duplicate-ness, though, and leaving this open. Others can decide if this is a duplicate of https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67330/23970.  (accidentally deleted)

Comment: I have noticed this in SEVERAL questions recently about magic items/weapons as equipment being compared to the spell *Magic Weapon*....which has absolutely NO bearing. It is becoming a pattern now. Why are people thinking those are connected in any way?

Answer (score 16):

## No.

Unlike prior editions, there is no requirement for a weapon to have an enhancement bonus before having other magical effects. A [Sword of Wounding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sword-of-wounding) is a magical weapon with no extra bonus to hit.

Some wondrous items can function as magic weapons, but that only helps them bypass resistances.

Compare the [Staff of Charming](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-charming):

> The staff can also be used as a magic quarterstaff.

...to the [Staff of the Magi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-magi):

> This staff can be wielded as a magic quarterstaff that grants a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it.

Each item specifies if it can be used as a magic weapon in addition to its other functions. Some items, like the [Staff of Healing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-healing), don't get the benefit of dealing magical damage simply because they don't say they can. It's still a quarterstaff (*DMG*, p. 140), but it doesn't count as magic for whacking people (probably has something to do with the fact that it's magic is about healing, not harming).

### In short...

The item does exactly what the DMG says - no more, no less.

Answer (score 4):

In general, magic items do what they say they do and no more.

On DMG p.140 it says:

> Unless a staff's description says otherwise, a staff can be used as a quarterstaff.

and:

> Whether crafted for some fell purpose or forged to
>   serve the highest ideals of chivalry, magic weapons are
>   coveted by many adventurers.
>
> Some magic weapons specify the type of weapon
>   they are in their descriptions, such as a longsword or longbow. If a magic weapon doesn't specify its weapon
>   type, you may choose the type or determine it randomly.

A *Staff of Healing* is a weapon (specifically a quarterstaff): it is **also** a magic weapon which allows it to bypass resistance/immunity. However, it does not get any bonus to hit or to damage.